# Testament of Youth meaning

Tags: meaning

In the famous autobiography '**Testament of Youth**' by Vera Brittain, what the word '**Testament**' means? Does it mean '**testimony**', '**era**', or '**pledge**'/'**promise**'?

Answer (score 1):

We can take our own meaning from titles and in my opinion , Testament in this context, means testimony; an account given as proof.

Comment: Probably with some Biblical/religious connotations.